# How do I get the IDs from firestore into the object arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

working on a React/Firestore app, trying to get the Id-s back into the objects array.
Here is the code:

```
  function getEm() {
    setLoading(true);
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const items = [];
      const ids = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        items.push(doc.data());
        ids.push(doc.id);
      });
      //unzipped
      setItems(items);
      setIds(ids);
      console.log(ids);
      console.log(items);
      //zipped
      const item = _.zipObject([(ids = [])], [(items = [])]);
      setItems(item);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }
```

Any idea on what is wrong with the '_zipObject' line?

Comment: Please describe the problem with the '_zipObject' line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add the id to the data object as soon as you get it from the query snapshot:

```
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
   const newItem = {
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id
   }
   items.push(newItem);
});
```

This would give you an array of object with all the data from the object + the id